# Why image(90000) is not correct when we can store 2G in binary or image type

Tags: sql-server

ProfilePicture – image with size up to 900KB.

I need a column in the table with these details how can I define these in SQL but not more than 900kb.

Comment: Use varbinary(max)

Comment: max is 2G I do not want to let more than 900kb

Comment: So use a check constraint on datalength if you need the database to enforce this

Comment: do 901kb and 900kb have the same length?

Comment: How would they? They are clearly different lengths...

Comment: To expand on the comment from @DaleK, you should use varbinary(max) because the ntext, text and image data types have been [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql) for many years and should not be used in new applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below the script

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable
(
    ImageColumn varbinary(max) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT CHK_YourTable_ImageColumn 
    CHECK (DATALENGTH(ImageColum) <= 900000)
)
```

Comment: Try again please